# Prove variance of mean estimator of an AR(1) model

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, autoregressive

I need to solve the proof as given in the screenshot below. I had tried to do something (under My solution) but I don't know how to proceed with the proof. I'm not sure whether I did something wrong or mistake. Please help me to continue with the proof. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: Ops! Sorry, that is a typo. I had edited the question again, please help me for this question. Thanks!

Comment: Please try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: Look up variance and autocovariance of ar1 process on Wikipedia

Comment: I did look up some related article and website but still couldn't solve it, that's why I hope I'm able to get some help from this forum. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the infomation, however, I'm still unable to get the final result that I want after 4 hours of trying, do you mind to share your steps to achieve the proof? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the information! It helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute directly (not the best homework question, if that's what this is):

\begin{align*}
Var(\bar{Y}) &= Var(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n Y_t) \\
             &= \frac{1}{n^2} Var( \sum_{t=1}^n Y_t) \\
             &= \frac{1}{n} \gamma(0) + 2 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{h = 1}^{n-h} \frac{n-h}{n} \gamma(h),
\end{align*}
where $\gamma(h) = \frac{\beta^h}{1-\beta^2}$ is the autocovariance function at lag $h$.

Substituting $\gamma(0) = \frac{1}{1-\beta^2}$ gives the first term in your sum
$$ 
\frac{1}{n} \gamma(0) = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1-\beta^2}.
$$

Similarly,
\begin{align*}
2 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{h = 1}^{n-h} \frac{n-h}{n} \gamma(h) &= \frac{2}{n^2(1-\beta^2)}  \sum_{h=1}^{n-h} (n-h) \beta^h \\
&=  \frac{2}{n^2(1-\beta^2)}  \sum_{h=1}^{n-h} \sum_{j=1}^{n-h} \beta^j \\ 
&=  \frac{2}{n^2(1-\beta^2)}  \sum_{h=1}^{n-h} ( \frac{1-\beta^{n+1-h}}{1-\beta}) \\
&=  \frac{2}{n^2(1-\beta^2)(1-\beta)}  \sum_{h=1}^{n-h} ( 1-\beta^{n+1-h} )\\
&= \cdots.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your great solution! It helps me a lot with my problem! May I know what technique I should use to solve for the ∑(1−β^(n+1−h)) ? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the link, and the solution! Have a nice day